# retrieving value from a dynamic selection list

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am working on a jsp project where I have a dynamic selection list. The values in this list change according to the value selected in the 1st selection list.
Here's the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function optionsChange(){   
    var service = document.getElementById("service").value;
    if(service == 'GSM'){   
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").value= '';
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'block';
        $('gsmService').attr('name', 'services');
    }else if(service == 'CDMA'){
        document.getElementById("gsmService").value= '';
        document.getElementById("gsmService").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("cdmaService").style.display = 'block';
        $('cdmaService').attr('name', 'services');
    }
  }
</script>

<select id="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();">
            <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
            <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
</select>

<td id="gsmService" ><select name="services" > 

            <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>  
            <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
            <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
</select>   
</td>

<td id="cdmaService" style="display:none"><select name="services" >
            <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
             <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
            <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>          
        </select>
 </td>
```

now when the user selects a service, lets say "GSM", and then selects a service from the second list, lets say "ASTRO". He clicks on a button which redirects him to the next page where he sees "ASTRO" printed. This works fine. 
But if the user selects "CDMA" from the 1st list and then selects, let's say "VOICE CHAT" from the second list. It still prints "ASTRO" on the next page. IT should print "VOICE CHAT".

this is the method to submit form:

```
<script language=javascript>

function submitForm(actionStr)
{
    if(actionStr=="User Details")
    {
        document.login.action="showUsrDetail.jsp";
        document.login.submit();
    } 
}
```

this is the code for the button:

```
<input type="button" value="User Details" onclick="submitForm(this.value);"/>
```

then it redirects to the page ""showUsrDetail.jsp". And when it does the name of the service is printed on the console. For which the code is:

```
<% 
    String service = request.getParameter("services");
    System.out.println("Value Added Service selected is ="+service);
%>
```

if i change the first selection to CDMA and then select any service from the second selection list, it still prints the Service which is under GSM.

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: It's very simple. Select `VOICE CHAT` before selecting `CDMA` because once first select box is changed it calls the method `optionsChange` and at that time only `ASTRO` is selected.

Comment: how can i select VOICE CHAT before selecting CDMA? The options COMBO OFFER CDMA, WIN THE DREAM and VOICE CHAT appear in the second selection list only after i've selected CDMA in the first selection list.

Comment: So apply change listener on second select item as well. change listener on first select will populate the second one and change listener on second select will send the request to the service.

Comment: can you show me a little bit how it's done?

Comment: can your share the code what are you doing on button click or how are you redirecting to next page.

Comment: is it ok? or should i change something it it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing nothing in `submitForm()` function other that submitting the form that can be achieved directly by `<input type="submit>"` as shown in below sample.

```
<form action="showUsrDetail.jsp" id="login" method="post">
    <!-- other fields -->
    <input type="submit" value="User Details"/>
</form>
```

---

### Solution 1

Use different names for all the select fields and check the values in `showUsrDetail.jsp`.

```
<form id="login" action="showUsrDetail.jsp" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><select id="service" onChange="javascript:optionsChange();"
                name="service">
                    <option value="GSM">GSM</option>
                    <option value="CDMA">CDMA</option>
            </select></td>
            <td id="gsmService"><select name="gsmService">
                    <option value="COMBO OFFER">COMBO OFFER</option>
                    <option value="CRICKET">CRICKET</option>
                    <option value="ASTRO">ASTRO</option>
            </select></td>

            <td id="cdmaService" style="display: none"><select
                name="cdmaService">
                    <option value="COMBO OFFER CDMA">COMBO OFFER CDMA</option>
                    <option value="WIN THE DREAM">WIN THE DREAM</option>
                    <option value="VOICE CHAT">VOICE CHAT</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="User Details" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

showUsrDetail.jsp:

```
<c:if test="${param.service == 'GSM'}">
    <c:out value="${param.gsmService}" />
</c:if>

<c:if test="${param.service == 'CDMA'}">
    <c:out value="${param.cdmaService}" />
</c:if>
```

---

### Solution 2

Add a `hidden input` field and update its value based on selection change in `cdmaService` and `gsmService` select item. Add change listener on both the select item.

```
<input type="hidden" name="serviceValue"/>
```

showUsrDetail.jsp:

```
<c:out value="${param.serviceValue}" />
```

---

***Note:***

> I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and *less error prone*.

Comment: there are other pages also.. i cannot directly pass USER DETAILS. in code i've shown user details. but in the method submitform() there are  more pages like activation.jsp, deactivation.jsp, etc etc. You were saying something about adding an even listner to the dynamic selection list. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: Let me update my post. The problem is due to same name used for both select.

Comment: if i use different name for both selection lists, what will i pass here in place of services?
  `String service = request.getParameter("services")`

Comment: Simply create a hidden input field in the form `<input type="hidden" name="services"/>` and set the value in when `gsmService` or `cdmaService` select field is changed. Since both the select filed have a same name hence you are always getting selected value of first one. Or use different names for all the select field and in the `showUsrDetail.jsp` select any one based on value of `service` parameter.

Comment: or you can do one thing in your code as well. Simply remove the `name` attribute of the previous select field when changed. There must be exactly single field with name attribute as `services`.

Comment: i'll try this and get back to you with the results.. thanks in advance :)

Comment: i wrote a function to get the selected values from both the lists.. ti worked..!! thank you :)

Comment: If the problem solved then close the thread. Visit [stackoverflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)